# SQL queries avg difference showing error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to find difference between two avg giving error?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7160d/9

```
select * from
(
select avg(avg_stars) as avg_1
from
(
select r.mid, avg(stars) as avg_stars
from
rating r inner join movie m
on r.mid = m.mid
where year < '1980'
group by r.mid
)
)
-
(
select avg(avg_stars) as avg_2
from
(
select r.mid, avg(stars) as avg_stars
from
rating r inner join movie m
on r.mid = m.mid
where year > '1980'
group by r.mid
)
)
```

Comment: Why is `stars` declared as `varchar` when it should (apparently) only contain numerical data?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks datatype mismatch it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be "littlbe bit" simplified

```
select 
avg(case when year < '1980' then stars end) -
avg(case when year > '1980' then stars end)
from movie m
inner join
(select mId, Cast(stars as int) as stars from Rating) r
on m.mID = r.mID
```

or (remove the cast if stars is of correct type)

```
select 
avg(case when year < '1980' then cast (stars as int) end) -
avg(case when year > '1980' then cast(stars as int) end)
from movie m
inner join
Rating r
on m.mID = r.mID
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7160d/58)

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want.

```
select 
(
select avg(avg_stars) as avg_1
from
(
select r.mid, avg(convert(int,stars)) as avg_stars
from
rating r inner join movie m
on r.mid = m.mid
where year < '1980'
group by r.mid
) x
) 
-

(
select avg(avg_stars) as avg_2
from
(
select r.mid, avg(convert(int,stars)) as avg_stars
from
rating r inner join movie m
on r.mid = m.mid
where year > '1980'
group by r.mid
) x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit another way to do it:

```
select [stats].Period, avg([stats].stars) as avg_stars    
from 
(
  select
    stars, 
    (case when year > '1980' then 'after 1980' else 'before 1980' end) as [Period]  
  from rating r inner join movie m on r.mid = m.mid
) [stats]
group by [stats].Period
```

(or you could have period as `date` in case you had `year` as `date`)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bf4e/26